# WPF MVVM UserControls

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

Например в одном окне 3-4 `usercontrol`'а, у каждого своя `ViewModel`. У них есть события, что какие-то данные изменились. Как правильно подписать на эти события с точки зрения MVVM? Или просто каждому контролу дать имя и в `CodeBehind` подписаться ?

Comment: Приведите пример исходного кода, какие именно события Вы имеете в виду? При использовании MVVM Вам не следует писать что-то в CodeBehind.

Answer (score 2):

Как и обычно: вы привязываете данные в ваших `UserControl`'ax через Binding к вашей VM. Это единственный правильный путь, другого пути нет.

События об изменении данных — неправильный путь, контролы должны выставлять dependency property, а не event'ы. (Event'ы выставлять можно, но лишь дополнительно.)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так. Объект реализует интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`, в этом случае View будет автоматически информирована о изменении данных в объекте через связывание данных binding.